# Modelmapper circular mapping

Tags: modelmapper

I've parent and child class with respective DTO's as follows

```
class Parent {
    List<Child> children;
    // setters and getters
}

class Child {
    Parent parent;
}

class ParentDto {
    List<ChildDto> children;
    // setters and getters
}

class ChildDto {
    ParentDto parent;
    // setters and getters
}
```

When I try to map Parent to ParentDto I'm getting StackOverflowError.

Please help me in resolving the issue.

Comment: This sould work. Please add the real properties and modelmapper configuration

Comment: @Pau I'm mapping like below mentioned `modelMapper.map(parents, new TypeToken<List<ParentDto>>() {}.getType()); `

Answer (score 0):

I know this post is old but I will try to give one answer in case someone from google to arrived here.

Probably you have a dynamic object creation.

Recently I had a problem like this. In my case I have a class Student that extends Person. And Person has three others attributes of type Person: father, mother and responsible. In case, I had a circularity relationship. When I ran my JUnits tests I got a circularity calls. I did't get a stakOverflow because the Spring (after some time) closes the data base connections.

I resolved this problem removing the dynamics objects creations from my Person class.

Another approach to solve this problem is adding a Condition in your mapper. You can read more about conditions [here](http://modelmapper.org/user-manual/property-mapping/#conditional-mapping). For example, you can have some Conditions saying: "If the person attribute id is 10, then, doesn't need map it.". This way we can avoid infinity mapping.
Well, let's see some snippeds of code:

Student class:

```
public class Student extends Person implements IStudent {

    private Person financialResponsible;

    // Getters and setters.

}
```

Person class:

```
public class Person implements IPerson {

    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private Person father;
    private Person mother;
    private Person responsible;
    private Address address;

    // Getters and setters.

    // This is my real problem. I removed it and the mapper worked.
    public IPerson getFather() {
        if (father == null) father = new Person();
        return father; 
    }
}
```

StudentDTO class:

```
public class StudentDTO extends PersonDTO {

    private PersonDTO financialResponsible;

    // Getters and setters.
}
```

PersonDTO class:

```
public class PersonDTO {

    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private PersonDTO father;
    private PersonDTO mother;
    private PersonDTO responsible;
    private AddressDTO address;

    // Getters and setters.

}
```

Here is a example of conditions:

```
...
import org.modelmapper.Condition;
...

    ModelMapper mapper = new ModelMapper();

    // Define STRICT to give high precision on mapper.
    mapper.getConfiguration().setMatchingStrategy(MatchingStrategies.STRICT);

    /*
     * Create conditions to avoid infinity circularity.
     */
    // Condidions.
    final Condition<IStudent, StudentDTO> fatherIsTen = mappingContext -> mappingContext.getSource().getFather().getId() == 10;
    final Condition<IStudent, StudentDTO> motherIsTen = mappingContext -> mappingContext.getSource().getMother().getId() == 10;
    final Condition<IStudent, StudentDTO> resposibleIsTen = mappingContext -> mappingContext.getSource().getResponsible().getId() == 10;

    // Adding conditions on mapper.
    mapper.createTypeMap(IStudent.class, StudentDTO.class) //
       .addMappings(mapper -> mapper.when(fatherIsTen).skip(StudentDTO::setFather))
       .addMappings(mapper -> mapper.when(motherIsTen).skip(StudentDTO::setMother))
       .addMappings(mapper -> mapper.when(resposibleIsTen).skip(StudentDTO::setResponsible));
```

I hope help o/